# In Informatica, How to ignore a comma that comes in one of the columns of a table

Tags: informatica

I have table column has the following format

Country                                 sales
Canada , United State , Japan           100

I use Informatica load the data into Flat file .csv format, session setting is :column delimited is , (comma),

so the result is not my expected :
Country     sales
Canada     United State     Japan        100

How to fix it ,so it comes like this

Country                                sales
Canada , United State , Japan           100

Comment: I'd need to see the mapping. How's your target created, what are the ports and definitions as well as session and target properties.

Comment: You can enclose all data with double quote ("). This will ensure you dont lost any comma separated data in a csv file. So, you can concat any field like this - out_column '"'||inp_column||'"'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a transformation i.e. `EXPTRANS / Expression` in your mapping then you may replace any `,` using reg_replace.

```
REG_REPLACE( column_name_in, ',+', ' ', 999999999)
```

[image]

Informatica is an ETL. Export `Transform` and Loading tool. Utilize it :)